# Javafx TextFormatter Backspacing issue

Tags: java, javafx

I am using **javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter** for format textfield into a currency field. Below shows my code.

```
private static final double DEFAULT_VALUE = 0.00d;
private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOL = "Rs"; //
public static final DecimalFormat CURRENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT
        = new DecimalFormat(CURRENCY_SYMBOL + "###,##0.00");

public static TextFormatter<Double> currencyFormatter() {
    return new TextFormatter<Double>(new StringConverter<Double>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Double value) {
            return CURRENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT.format(value);
        }

        @Override
        public Double fromString(String string) {
            try {
                return CURRENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT.parse(string).doubleValue();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return Double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }, DEFAULT_VALUE,
            change -> {
                try {
                    CURRENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT.parse(change.getControlNewText());
                    return change;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    );
}

//format textfield into a currency formatted field
text_field.setTextFormatter(SomeClass.currencyFormatter());
```

Everything works fine except I cannot backspace out the whole textfield.

[image]

Any help would be appreciable. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of TextFormatter.getFilter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#getFilter--):

> The filter itself is an `UnaryOperator` that accepts `TextFormatter.Change` object. It should return a `TextFormatter.Change` object that contains the actual (filtered) change. **Returning null rejects the change.**

If the text has no digits, it cannot be parsed, in which case you are returning null, which causes the typing change to be rejected.

One option is to simplify your TextFormatter:

```
return new TextFormatter<Number>(
    new NumberStringConverter(CURRENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT));
```